# How to create dynamic layout with edittext , textview and images with given input number in previous screen android?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

Hi in previous screen, say for eg: if user selects 2, then in next screen I need to display as,

static image> followed by Student No 1. --> TextView

Student Name-->TextView
-> EditText

Roll No------> TextView
 -> EditText

static image> Student No 2. --> TextView

Student Name-->TextView
-> EditText

Roll No------> TextView
 -> EditText

So based on the given input, the given fields should increase. How to do and proceed. Please help me.

Thanks.

Here is what I tried and strucked.
[From the given link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34654799/3500826) 
I got the required number and stored in preference.

String number = mPreference.getStringFromPreference("number");
//say for eg: this number has 2

How to dynamically increase the layout fields based on given input.

Here is xml design and static xml design of my output.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="#EAEAEA">
  <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/personal_info_container_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/nav_login_grey"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/numbers"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="Student No:1"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Telephone">
            </TextView>

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:ems="10"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_border"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/editText" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Email*"/>

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:ems="10"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_border"
                android:id="@+id/email" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Next"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:background="#8C8C8C"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:textAllCaps="false"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is static output.

[image]

But expected output should be in dynamic generation based on given input.
[image]

Please help me to solve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) or [ListView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html). They meant to be used for dynamic views like in your case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [RecyclerView](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/) for this, just update the size of list items every time and you have to create view (that is list item) only once in a separate xml.

Comment: Thanks..Do you have any example or reference link?

Comment: Have you checked the link I have attached to RecyclerView http://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/ .It has very well explained the example.What you just need to do is replace your view with his view.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Customize as per your need.

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
   i.putExtra("VALUE", 2); //Dynamic value
   startActivity(i);


}

}
```

SecondActivity

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

LinearLayout LLMain;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second);

    LLMain = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.Linearroot);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    int Value = intent.getIntExtra("VALUE", 0);

    for(int i = 0;i < Value;i++)
    {
        CreateLayout(i);
    }

}

public void CreateLayout(int val)
{
    LinearLayout LLTop = new LinearLayout(this);
    LLTop.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

    LinearLayout LLBtm = new LinearLayout(this);
    LLBtm.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramT,paramB,param1,param2,param3,param4,param5,param6;

    paramT = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    paramT.setMargins(20, 10, 20, 10);

    paramB = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    paramB.setMargins(20, 10, 20, 10);

    param1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    param2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    param2.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL;

    param3 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    param4 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    param5 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    param6 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
    iv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText("Student" + val);


    TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
    tv1.setText("Phone");

    TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);
    tv2.setText("Email");

    EditText et = new EditText(this);

    EditText et1 = new EditText(this);

    LLTop.addView(iv, param1);
    LLTop.addView(tv, param2);

    LLBtm.addView(tv1, param3);
    LLBtm.addView(et, param4);
    LLBtm.addView(tv2,param5);
    LLBtm.addView(et1,param6);


    LLMain.addView(LLTop, paramT);
    LLMain.addView(LLBtm,paramB);


}

}
```

second.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/Linearroot"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".SecondActivity" >

</LinearLayout>
```

**Hope it helps.!**

Answer (score 0):

If you have limited items to add dynamically means add your edittext or textview or views by creating a RelativityLayout or LinearLayout and add the view using addView() method OR if you have unlimited items to add dynamically means use ListView or RecyclerView